# Placing a SearchBar in the top/navigation bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Forms project, is it possible to place a SearchBar such that it appears in the top/navigation bar of the app? What I want to achieve is something along the lines of the Android Youtube app, just cross-platform:

[image]

Comment: did you get solution for that.i need same in xamarin forms

Comment: @SANDEEP I have long since stopped using Xamarin unfortunately, so I'm not sure what the current way of doing this is. Did you try any of the answers?

Answer (score 5):

To do this, you should write a renderer for your Page

There is my implementation for iOS (with custom 'searchField')

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using MyControls;
using MyRenderer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySearchContentPage), typeof(MySearchContentPageRenderer))]

namespace IOS.Renderer
{
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

    public class MySearchContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            SetSearchToolbar();
        }

        public override void WillMoveToParentViewController(UIKit.UIViewController parent)
        {
            base.WillMoveToParentViewController(parent);

            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem;
                parent.NavigationItem.TitleView = NavigationItem.TitleView;
            }
        }

        private void SetSearchToolbar()
        {
            var element = Element as MySearchContentPage;
            if (element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var width = NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Width;
            var height = NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;
            var searchBar = new UIStackView(new CGRect(0, 0, width * 0.85, height));

            searchBar.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center;
            searchBar.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;
            searchBar.Spacing = 3;

            var searchTextField = new MyUITextField();
            searchTextField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(239, 239, 239);
            NSAttributedString strAttr = new NSAttributedString("Search", foregroundColor: UIColor.FromRGB(146, 146, 146));
            searchTextField.AttributedPlaceholder = strAttr;
            searchTextField.SizeToFit();

            // Delete button
            UIButton textDeleteButton = new UIButton(new CGRect(0, 0, searchTextField.Frame.Size.Height + 5, searchTextField.Frame.Height));
            textDeleteButton.Font = UIFont.FromName("FontAwesome", 18f);
            textDeleteButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            textDeleteButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(146, 146, 146), UIControlState.Normal);
            textDeleteButton.SetTitle("\uf057", UIControlState.Normal);
            textDeleteButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
            {
                searchTextField.Text = string.Empty;
            };

            searchTextField.RightView = textDeleteButton;
            searchTextField.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

            // Border
            searchTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
            searchTextField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB(239, 239, 239).CGColor;
            searchTextField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            searchTextField.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
            searchTextField.EditingChanged += (sender, e) => 
            { 
                element.SetValue(MySearchContentPage.SearchTextProperty, searchTextField.Text);
            };

            searchBar.AddArrangedSubview(searchTextField);

            var searchbarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(searchBar);
            NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(searchbarButtonItem, true);

            NavigationItem.TitleView = new UIView();

            if (ParentViewController != null)
            {
                ParentViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem;
                ParentViewController.NavigationItem.TitleView = NavigationItem.TitleView;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there is some discussion:[How to include view in NavigationBar of Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846074/how-to-include-view-in-navigationbar-of-xamarin-forms)

[image]

I hope, you understood the main idea.

Comment: Hello @Vitaliy! I tried to implement your solution in a Xamarin Forms with Prism project and it "almost" works. My problem is that when the Search page is presented the search text field disappears and the "Back" title on the left is displayed. Did you have something like this? There is some event that creates that "Back" title after ViewWillAppear event.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out. It was a plugin I'm using that changed Navigation behavior (Iconize).