# How to add a SearchBar to the top of page like toolbaritems icon with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using masterdetail page within this page i am using tabbed page now i want to show toolbar icon and search bar on the top of page.i am able to place toolbar icon but struggling with search bar.how to place it at the top its behavior should match with the search bar in whatsapp app and in youtube app

Comment: Please consider marking as an answer/upvoting if an answer helped you.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

The WhatsApp search bar is just that, a `SearchBar` control which you can add to your XAML layout as follows:

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" Text="{Binding Filter}" />
    <ListView ItemSource="{Binding Items}">
        ...
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Ensure you have a backing property for the filter. You can use the setter of this property to intercept people filtering the data and filter the `Items` property accordingly.

The YouTube search behaves a bit differently. The toolbar item pops a new screen modally where the search is handled similar to a [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller) (on iOS). There is no Xamarin Forms drop-in control (that I'm aware of) that does this for you so you'll probably have to roll your own.

Comment: Do you have any example

Comment: No, the above is the sample.

Comment: the above sample i can not use in toolbar item and it wont work according to my requirements

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you any further then. As far as I'm concerned StackOverflow is meant to point people in the right direction so they can figure out their issues on their own and not to build their projects for them which is the vibe I'm getting here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

We can create a custom renderer on both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android to accomplish it.

Here's a sample application for reference:
https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends

And here's a blog post that shows how to add a search bar to a Xamarin.Forms app for both Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android: https://www.codetraveler.io/2019/08/10/adding-a-search-bar-to-xamarin-forms-navigationpage/

#### App.cs

Use a [Xamarin.Forms Platform-Specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.iosspecific.navigationpage.setpreferslargetitles?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) to use LargeTitles on the Xamarin.iOS app.

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;

public class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var navigationPage = new Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());

        navigationPage.On<iOS>().SetPrefersLargeTitles(true);

        MainPage = navigationPage;
    }
}
```

#### ISearchPage Interface

Create an Interface that can be used across the Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects.

```cs
public interface ISearchPage
{
    void OnSearchBarTextChanged(in string text);
    event EventHandler<string> SearchBarTextChanged;
}
```

#### Xamarin.Forms Page

```cs
public class MyContentPage : ContentPage, ISearchPage
{
    public MyContentPage()
    {
        SearchBarTextChanged += HandleSearchBarTextChanged
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> SearchBarTextChanged;

    public void OnSearchBarTextChanged(in string text) => SearchBarTextChanged?.Invoke(this, text);

    void HandleSearchBarTextChanged(object sender, string searchBarText)
    {
        //Logic to handle updated search bar text
    }     
}
```

#### iOS Custom Renderer

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UIKit;
using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyContentPage), typeof(SearchPageRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOS
{
    public class SearchPageRenderer : PageRenderer, IUISearchResultsUpdating
    {
        readonly UISearchController _searchController;

        public SearchPageRenderer()
        {
            _searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null)
            {
                SearchResultsUpdater = this,
                DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
                HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false,
                HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            };
            _searchController.SearchBar.Placeholder = string.Empty;
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            if (ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController is null)
            {
                ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController = _searchController;
                DefinesPresentationContext = true;

                //Work-around to ensure the SearchController appears when the page first appears https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313164/5953643
                ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController.Active = true;
                ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController.Active = false;
            }
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController = null;
        }

        public void UpdateSearchResultsForSearchController(UISearchController searchController)
        {
            if (Element is ISearchPage searchPage)
                searchPage.OnSearchBarTextChanged(searchController.SearchBar.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Xamarin.Android Menu XML

1. In the Xamarin.Android project, in the `Resources` folder, create a new folder called `menu`  (if one doesn't already exist).

   - **Note**: the folder, `menu`, has a lowercase 'm'
2. In the `Resources > menu` folder, create a new file called `MainMenu.xml`.

[image]

3. Open `Resources > menu > MainMenu.xml`
4. In `MainMenu.xml` add the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/ActionSearch"
        android:title="Filter"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

#### Xamarin.Android CustomRenderer

Uses the [Plugin.CurrentActivity NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/).

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyContentPage), typeof(SearchPageRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.Droid
{
    public class SearchPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public SearchPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            if (Element is ISearchPage && Element is Page page && page.Parent is NavigationPage navigationPage)
            {
                //Workaround to re-add the SearchView when navigating back to an ISearchPage, because Xamarin.Forms automatically removes it
                navigationPage.Popped += HandleNavigationPagePopped;
                navigationPage.PoppedToRoot += HandleNavigationPagePopped;
            }
        }

        //Adding the SearchBar in OnSizeChanged ensures the SearchBar is re-added after the device is rotated, because Xamarin.Forms automatically removes it
        protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            if (Element is ISearchPage && Element is Page page && page.Parent is NavigationPage navigationPage && navigationPage.CurrentPage is ISearchPage)
            {
                AddSearchToToolbar(page.Title);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (GetToolbar() is Toolbar toolBar)
                toolBar.Menu?.RemoveItem(Resource.Menu.MainMenu);

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        //Workaround to re-add the SearchView when navigating back to an ISearchPage, because Xamarin.Forms automatically removes it
        void HandleNavigationPagePopped(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is NavigationPage navigationPage
                && navigationPage.CurrentPage is ISearchPage)
            {
                AddSearchToToolbar(navigationPage.CurrentPage.Title);
            }
        }

        void AddSearchToToolbar(string pageTitle)
        {
            if (GetToolbar() is Toolbar toolBar
                && toolBar.Menu?.FindItem(Resource.Id.ActionSearch)?.ActionView?.JavaCast<SearchView>().GetType() != typeof(SearchView))
            {
                toolBar.Title = pageTitle;
                toolBar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.MainMenu);

                if (toolBar.Menu?.FindItem(Resource.Id.ActionSearch)?.ActionView?.JavaCast<SearchView>() is SearchView searchView)
                {
                    searchView.QueryTextChange += HandleQueryTextChange;
                    searchView.ImeOptions = (int)ImeAction.Search;
                    searchView.InputType = (int)InputTypes.TextVariationFilter;
                    searchView.MaxWidth = int.MaxValue; //Set to full width - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456102/searchview-doesnt-expand-full-width
                }
            }
        }

        void HandleQueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Element is ISearchPage searchPage)
                searchPage.OnSearchBarTextChanged(e.NewText);
        }

        Toolbar GetToolbar() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    }
}
```

## Sample App

Here's a sample app for reference:
https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends

And a blog post that shows how to add a search bar for both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android: https://www.codetraveler.io/2019/08/10/adding-a-search-bar-to-xamarin-forms-navigationpage/

[image: iOS Gif]

Comment: First, Thank you so much @Brandon-Minnick I implemented it succesfully. However, It did not work on a TabbedPage. Any idea why?

Comment: @acido Is your ContentPage in a NavigationPage?

Comment: My content page is under a tabbed page and the tabbed page is under a navigation page. cc: @Brandon Minnick

Answer (score 0):

Used User Control for Navbar. and hide Navigarionbar using

NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);

Comment: create custom navigation bar using grid or stack.

Comment: see this url https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/07/07/custom-app-header-in-forms/      like this. you can chage navbar design per your design requerments

Comment: I am getting error...i had follow the same steps

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 7:14. StaticResource not found for key MainPageTemplate

Comment: it's Xaml Parse error so something wrong in XAML file

Comment: i am able to run the code now...but it is not like my requirement ...i want to show search bar when user tap on search icon

Comment: use can visible SearchBar Control when click on Serach Icon in User Control

Comment: check my another ans links may be it's help you

Answer (score 0):

Check following link may be it's help you. and i think it's for your requirement.

http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar/

[Placing a SearchBar in the top/navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047041/placing-a-searchbar-in-the-top-navigation-bar)

[How to include view in NavigationBar of Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846074/how-to-include-view-in-navigationbar-of-xamarin-forms)

install or update Android support repository, google play service and Google USB driver

[image]

Comment: i tried first link yesterday there are some support library issue was there i spend 1 day to get out of it but i cant ..so try to get solution from other options and in second and third link there is no solution for android ....what about android

Answer (score 0):

if you'r using shell app you can use Shell.TitleView instead of Navigation.TitleView as the following :

```
        <Shell.TitleView>

        <SearchBar x:Name="search"  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>



        </Shell.TitleView>
```