# how to use SearchBar in ToolBarItems in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to use SearchBar in ToolBarItems? Like in whatsapp there is search icon on right hand side and when you click on it search bar open.
I tired it wasnt working.
Can anybody help me.

Comment: You asked the exact same question not too long ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302537/how-to-add-a-searchbar-to-the-top-of-page-like-toolbaritems-icon-with-xamarin-fo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a SearchBar to the top of page like toolbaritems icon with Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302537/how-to-add-a-searchbar-to-the-top-of-page-like-toolbaritems-icon-with-xamarin-fo)

Comment: ohh ....sorry my mistake .

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms doesn't allow you to add a SearchBar in the Navigation Bar

This sample app shows how to add the SearchBar just underneath the Navigation Bar:
https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp