# Show search bar in navigation bar without scrolling on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

I’m attaching a UISearchController to the `navigationItem.searchController` property of a UITableViewController on iOS 11. This works fine: I can use the nice iOS 11-style search bar.

However, I’d like to make the search bar visible on launch. By default, the user has to scroll up in the table view to see the search bar. Does anyone know how is this is possible?

[image]
[image]

*Left: default situation after launch. Right: search bar made visible (by scrolling up). I’d like to have the search bar visible after launch, as in the right screenshot.*

I already found that the search bar can be made visible by setting the property `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` of my navigation item to false. However, this causes the search bar to always be visible — even when scrolling down —, which is not what I want.

Comment: in where you added the code `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling`

Comment: what about setting it as s `firstResponder`?

Comment: The selected answer below works for me on load, but I'd also like to re-display the Search Controller when programmatically scrolling to the top with `scrollView.setContentOffset(_:animated)`. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: @Jonathan `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false` puts the search bar over large title in iOS 13. Any idea if I can update this somehow?

Comment: nothing works from answers, did someone solve issue?(

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The following makes the search bar visible at first, then allows it to hide when scrolling:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```

Using `isActive` didn't do what I wanted, it makes the search bar active (showing cancel button, etc.), when all I want is for it to be visible.

Comment: This solution works, but there are side effects if you are also displaying a navigation bar if it was previously hidden (i.e. pushing this view w/ search bar onto the navigation stack)

The search bar will appear static in place as the navigation bar animates. Looks awful :(

Comment: Not if you put the first part in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Can someone please elaborate on why this works and why `searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false` in viewDidLoad does not? The latter seems far more logical to me

Comment: This causes visual bug in iOS 13 on going back from child screen.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome the visual bug that this idea brings? The tableView 'jumps' when getting back from the child screen. The issue happens only if the view is scrolled from the top and the child view is opened and then closed.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the property `isActive` to `true` after adding the searchController to the `navigationItem`.

Just like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchController.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: No setter method 'setIsActive:'

Comment: You're right, @NikolayKrasnov. `isActive` is a read-only boolean. You will want to use `searchController.active = true`, instead.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked after adding following lines in `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController!.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 13, @Jordan Wood's answer didn't work.
Instead I did:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        searchController.isActive = true
        searchController.isActive = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost! The search bar animates to become visible after the view appears. This will annoy users. :(

Answer (score 1):

[@JordanWood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4055958/jordan-wood)'s answer caused a visual bug when popping VC from navigation stack back to the screen with SearchBar, so i came up with solution that fixed it

NOTE: This solution seems to be reasonable if your collection content will never overgrow `self.view`'s frame, otherwise u'll need to tune it a bit to get correct dynamic `collectionViewContentOffset`. i.e when user leaves the screen which is scrolled far down and comes back, `collectionView` will appear scrolled to top, which is mostly not what you want

```
private var collectionViewContentOffset: CGPoint?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    collectionView.setContentOffset(
        collectionViewContentOffset ?? .zero,
        animated: false
    )
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    if collectionViewContentOffset == nil {
        collectionViewContentOffset = CGPoint(
            x: 0,
            y: -view.safeAreaInsets.top
        )
    }
    
}
```

Another good solution i found (which works fine when collection's contentSize is bigger than `self.view`'s frame) is to run it like that:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
}
```

Downside of that option is that your searchBar will hide when you try to do a swipe up gesture on a `collectionView` (`collectionView's` `contentSize` needs to be smaller than `self.view`'s frame), leave the screen and come back. But there are no visual bugs, just the fact that it hides in one corner case

Answer (score 0):

```
For (iOS 13.0, *) and SwiftUI
```

> navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()

```
Example:

struct SearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
        let searchBar: SearchBar
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ViewControllerResolver { viewController in
                    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchBar.searchController
                    viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()

                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            )
    }
}
```