# Swift : show searchbar when scroll up and hide it when scroll down

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am new to Ios develpomment,
I added a `Searchbar` into the navigation item
What I would like to implement is when I scroll Up the `tableview` 
I want to hide the `Searchbar` and when show it when I scroll down

Like safari effect on iPAD /Iphone where the address bar is hiding when scrolling Down and showing when scrolling Up

```
  let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
  searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
  navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  definesPresentationContext = true
```

thank your for helping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is to hide and display your search bar when you start scrolling so for that you need to override the didBeginScrolling (check the exact name ) and add this code accordingly

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

more info is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352230/5123516