# Adding content on a custom content page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ok, so I am trying to add a searchbar in the toolbar of my page.

- The Search bar appears correctly in the toolbar and I can catch the on text changed event.
- I created a new Xaml and cs page and changed content page to 'MySearchContentPage'
- I Tried to add a grid and label on my new page created but nothing will show except for the searchbar. I added this just to see if I can get anything to display.

Am I adding it in the right place ? Or how do you add content to this page ?

I have done this by doing the following:

MySearchContentPage Class:

```
public class MySearchContentPage : ContentPage, ISearchPage
{

    public MySearchContentPage()
    {

        SearchBarTextChanged += HandleSearchBarTextChanged;

    }





    public event EventHandler<string> SearchBarTextChanged;

    public void OnSearchBarTextChanged(string text) => SearchBarTextChanged?.Invoke(this, text);

    void HandleSearchBarTextChanged(object sender, string searchBarText)
    {
        //Logic to handle updated search bar text

    }
}
```

ISearchPage:

```
public interface ISearchPage
{
    void OnSearchBarTextChanged(string text);
    event EventHandler<string> SearchBarTextChanged;


}
```

iOS renderer page:

```
public class MySearchContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer, IUISearchResultsUpdating
{
    readonly UISearchController searchController;


    bool _isFirstAppearing = true;

    public override void WillMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
    {
        base.WillMoveToParentViewController(parent);

        var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null)
        {
            SearchResultsUpdater = this,
            DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
            HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true,
            HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true



        };
        searchController.SearchBar.Placeholder = "Search Symptoms";



        parent.NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;

        DefinesPresentationContext = true;
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        //Work-around to ensure the SearchController appears when the page first appears https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313164/5953643
        if (_isFirstAppearing)
        {
            ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController.Active = true;
            ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SearchController.Active = false;

            _isFirstAppearing = false;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSearchResultsForSearchController(UISearchController searchController)
    {
        if (Element is ISearchPage searchPage)
            searchPage.OnSearchBarTextChanged(searchController.SearchBar.Text);
    }


public MySearchContentPageRenderer()
    {
       var searchControllerr = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null)
        {
            SearchResultsUpdater = this,
            DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
            HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false,
            HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        };
        searchControllerr.SearchBar.Placeholder = string.Empty;
    }


    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
        {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red
        };



    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
       //  base.ViewDidLoad();

      //  NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
      //  NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        //  var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);
        //  searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Default;
        // searchController.SearchBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        // NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;
        // NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;



        //searchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit();
        //searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent;
        ////NavigationController.TabBarController
        //this.sea
        //NavigationController.TabBarController.NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true;
        //NavigationController.TabBarController.NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;

        //this.Title = "Search";
    }








}
```

So far the outcome is this :

I can't seem to get anything else to add to this page. Can anyone explain why?

AddSymptomNew.xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<visiblegyapp:MySearchContentPage
xmlns:visiblegyapp="clr-namespace:VisiblegyApp"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="VisiblegyApp.AddSymptomNew"
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
ios:Page.LargeTitleDisplay="Always"
Title="Search Symptoms"
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BasePageColor}"

>
<ScrollView 
    x:Name="outerScrollView"
    Padding="0"
    >

    <Grid 
            x:Name="layeringGrid" 
            RowSpacing="0"

            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="test label" TextColor="Red"  Grid.Row="1"/>



    </Grid>






    </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: first, why do you need a custom renderer for this page?  Second, when you say you can't add any other elements, where are you attempting to do this?  Your XAML only includes a Grid and a Label.  Where is the ListView you are attempting to add?

Comment: @Jason I used a custom render for this page so I could have the searchbar in the nav bar, I tried to add it in by using titleview but it doesn't seem to work that way, is there a better way to do it ??. I tried to add other content in the XAML page, sorry that was a typo, I just added the grid and label in to see if it will display but I can't get it to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **cause** is ContentPage is inheritable while [XAML is not inheritable](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/239481/#Comment_239481).

I would recommend you to use a custom [contentview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentview?view=xamarin-forms) and add this contentView to MySearchContentPage .

For example, create a custom `contentView` here:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App132.AddSymptomNewView">
  <ContentView.Content>

        <ScrollView 
            x:Name="outerScrollView"
            Padding="0">

            <Grid 
                x:Name="layeringGrid" 
                RowSpacing="0"

                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Text="test label" TextColor="Red"  Grid.Row="1"/>

            </Grid>

        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And use it in the `MySearchContentPage` :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:app132="clr-namespace:App132"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App132.MainPage">

    <app132:AddSymptomNewView/>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, So I made a created a new content view as you suggested and added it into a new page, so currently my page xaml looks like this '<myapp:MySearchContentPage  xmlns:myapp="clr-namespace:myapp"
                                   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                                   x:Class="myapp.AddSym">


     <myapp:MyView/>


</myapp:MySearchContentPage>'. But it still doesn't seem to be displaying anything other than the searchbar.

Comment: @MarkPW I think the label is overlap by the searchBar. Try to add HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions:    `<app132:AddSymptomNewView VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>`.

Comment: Thanks that did it, the issue is now the nav bar is just staying white until you click the searchbar then it goes to the colour that is should, do you know why that is?

Comment: Red color? You should check the codes where you set the color, see if the code runs when the page created.