# Show search bar without having to scroll up first?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a search bar to my table view so it can filter settings for the user. [The only problem is it is initially hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ9ik.jpg) when the view first loads, giving no indication it is available.

It only [shows after you scroll up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DstdJ.jpg).

I found a solution that worked back in iOS 11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352230/7838349. Unfortunately it seems like [this implementation is rather buggy in iOS 13 and seems to no longer work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkeDX.jpg) and still seems to show after scrolling.

For reference this is the code I have with the buggy implementation:

```
class SelectSettingViewController : UITableViewController {
weak var delegate: SelectSettingDelegate?
var settings: [String] = []
var filteredSettings: [String] = []

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
  return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // 1
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    // 2
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    // 3
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search settings"
    // 4
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    // 5
    definesPresentationContext = true
    
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
}
```

Comment: did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62864576/6689101)

Comment: @zombie yep I did, it leaves the search controller active despite setting it to false.